# SwiperJS missing dependencies: swiper/types

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I'm trying to set up SwiperJS in a new Angular project following it's tutorial. But it shows an error of missing dependencies. Yet, I followed the steps provided [here](https://swiperjs.com/angular).

What does this issue mean and how can it be fixed?

```
The target entry-point "swiper_angular" has missing dependencies:
 - swiper/types
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to reinstall the modules

```
npm i swiper --save

rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

npm i
```

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'?

Comment: you're on windows ? :D
delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file instead of this command